# Normalize scroll bars across browsers?

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm looking to shim all modern browser so that the scroll bar acts the same way.

On newer macs the scroll bar hovers over content in webkit, on firefox the scroll takes about 15px of the content area. I'm wondering if anyone has see something that would gets these all to a similar state.

Thanks!

Comment: If you did normalize the scrollbars in such a way, they would look out of place on whatever platform they were running on except the platform you normalized them to.

Comment: Really though the appropriate approach to design in this realm is to be adaptive/responsive; web is not a print medium, it is futile to look for pixel-perfect design; your design should be fluid and adapt to the environment it has.  that's the nature of web.

Comment: @icktoofay who said I was normalizing them to a platform?

Comment: @JustinL please don't lecture me on design, that's not the question I asked.

Comment: If you're normalizing them to something that no platform uses, then *everyone's* alienated, rather than *almost* everyone.

Comment: @icktoofay you have a very closed view about the reasons why someone would want to do this...

Comment: Alright. It was just a caution.

Answer (score 0):

That's the browser's decision, you can't change the size of scrollbars in modern browsers.

What you could do, if it's really important that the scrollbars be the same in all browsers, is use a Javascript/jQuery library like [this one](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) or [this one](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)... But generally you should just use whatever content area you are given.